# Logging erroneous queries only on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, profiling, sql-server-profiler

I have what would seem to be an easy goal to accomplish, yet I have not found a good solution. Google does not shed a light on it and I just hope that I have been looking for a solution in wrong places or just tried to use tools in a wrong way...

Or perhaps it is already too late for me today to think clearly :) But this is where you can help me out, I hope.

I need to be able to log erroneous queries only which were executed on a specific instance of  SQL Server. I thought that SQL Profiler would allow me to do it in no time, but I have not been able to find a combination of settings that would allow me to log only those queries, that returned an error (most likely parsing error) + error details.

Imagine SQL Server with 100s of queries being executed each second, and only 1 or 2 improperly formed queries each day resulting with a parsing error. I just need to be able to come and see those 1-2 queries per day without having to run a very expensive profile for all queries on the system and having to dig through it each day.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? Extended Events has a much more flexible filtering architecture.

Comment: This particular instance is SQL Server 2005 based

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set up a trace for the [Exception Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187506.aspx), [SQL:BatchCompleted Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176010.aspx) and [RPC:Completed Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175543.aspx). Add a filter for `Error` not equal to 0. Start the trace. Done.

Comment: I knew it was too late for me to find the right solution... thanks, man! This was a great start and after some tweaking, I have just what I needed. Much appreciated.

Comment: When I tried this I got the exceptions but none of the `SQL:BatchCompleted` or `RPC:Completed` in my trace?

Comment: I also recommend adding [User Error Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190953.aspx) (to see detailed descriptions of the errors); and filter out `Error` 0, 5701 and 5703 (those last two codes are unimportant notifications)